# Dijkstra Algorithm not outputting correctly

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I am having trouble with implementing Dijkstra algorithm.

I have the following variables initialized :

```
enum GraphLimit300 {MAX_NODES = 50};
typedef unsigned int Element300;
Element300 adjacencyMatrix[MAX_NODES][MAX_NODES];
Element300 distanceArray[MAX_NODES];
bool visitedSet[MAX_NODES];
int numberNodes;
```

Here is my current implementation of the algorithm:
int startNode;
    int visited;

```
unsigned int smallest = UINT_MAX;
do
{
    startNode = getStartNode300();
    setVisitedSet300();
    smallest = UINT_MAX;
    visitedSet[startNode] = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberNodes; i++)
    {
        distanceArray[i] = adjacencyMatrix[startNode][i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberNodes - 1; i++)   
    {
        for (int v = 0; v < numberNodes; v++)
        {
            if (visitedSet[v] == false)
            {
                if (distanceArray[v] < smallest)
                {
                    smallest = distanceArray[v];
                    visited = v;
                }
            }
        }
        visitedSet[visited] = true;
        for (int w = 0; w < numberNodes; w++)
        {
            if (visitedSet[w] == false)
            {
                distanceArray[w] = min(distanceArray[w], distanceArray[visited] + adjacencyMatrix[visited][w]);
            }
        }
    }
```

On this particular for loop where it should do the certain math to find the min between values at a certain index where the nodes are false and store the min in that index. What I found is that after it chooses the smallest value in `distaceArray` and set it to true(which is 3 if I start at 1 using the data file below, Which is correct.).

```
    for (int w = 0; w < numberNodes; w++)
        {
            if (visitedSet[w] == false)
            {
                distanceArray[w] = min(distanceArray[w], distanceArray[visited] + adjacencyMatrix[visited][w]);
            }
        }
```

It uses the nodes '0' and '2' as of this particular iteration is the nodes that are false. And does the math for times and stores them in the wrong array.

I am using this data set that stores the numbers in `adjacencyMatrix` correctly.

```
0           5          10          4294967295
4294967295  0          4294967295  3
4294967295  7          0           4294967295
4294967295  4294967295 4           0
```

The correct output is:

```
Distance[0] =4294967295
Distance[1] =0 //Which is the node that I choose to start with
Distance[2] =7
Distance[3] =3
```

What I am getting is:

```
Distance[0] =3
Distance[1] =0
Distance[2] =3
Distance[3] =3
```

I have done this process by hand to confirm that the correct output that I should be getting is true and it IS.

Updated if:

```
if (visitedSet[w] == false && adjacencyMatrix[visited][w] != UINT_MAX)
                {
                    distanceArray[w] = min(distanceArray[w], distanceArray[visited] + adjacencyMatrix[visited][w]);
                }
```

Comment: I have to say this is a very inefficient way of doing Dijkstra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is again, the fact that you shall only consider edges which exist, that is `adjacencyMatrix[visited][w]!=UINT_MAX`.

If you don't exclude these edges, `distanceArray[visited] + adjacencyMatrix[visited][w]` will overflow and the `min()` will not return the result that you expect.

You can solve this by changing this line:

```
if (visitedSet[w] == false && adjacencyMatrix[visited][w]!=UINT_MAX )
```

**Edit:**

There is indeed another problem hidden in your nested for loops.  The first inner for loop looks each time for the shortest subpath to expland.  Unfortuantely, you didn't reset `smallest`,  so that it starts with the smalest value of the previous iteration.

Update the looping as follows and you'll get your explected result:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberNodes - 1; i++)   
{
    smallest = UINT_MAX; // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    for (int v = 0; v < numberNodes; v++) 
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: so when I do the calling of the `min()`  instead of `visitedSet(w) == false` add `adjacencyMatrix[visited[w]!= UINT_MAX`? with a logic and?

Comment: I did the thing you said and I am getting the same output.

Comment: I tried doing it on both if statements and that didn't work at all.

Comment: Here the corrected code as [online demo](http://ideone.com/tgysgR). It works.  I've removed your `do` loop as there was no `while` counterpart.  If you remove my correction, you'll get your wrong result.

Comment: I tried a different data set with 5 and it was the incorrect answer. [link](http://ideone.com/5gyj4T) The 60 should be 50 and the 100 should be 50.

Comment: Right:  the main problem has hidden a small initialisation issue.  I've edited the post, and [here](http://ideone.com/5t8eYi) the updated demo